# interface with System.IO Object cannot be completed in Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make an interface like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Foo
{
    public interface IStreamProvider
    {
        Stream OutputStream { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and implement it in the iOS project like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Foundation;
using Foo;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StreamProvider_iOS))]
namespace Foo.iOS
{
    public class StreamProvider_iOS :  IStreamProvider
    {
        public Stream OutputStream { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but I end up getting this error:

> 'StreamProvider_iOS ' does not implement interface member
>   'IStreamProvider.OutputStream'. 'StreamProvider_iOS.OutputStream'
>   cannot implement 'IStreamProvider.OutputStream' because it does not
>   have the matching return type of 'Stream'.

I'm thinking it's because System.IO in the base xamarin project isn't the same as System.IO in the Xamarin.iOS project, but I'm not really sure and don't know how to work around that if it's the case.

Comment: You haven't shown your `using` directives - do you have `using System.IO;` in both cases?

Comment: What type of projects are your interface and class definitions in?

Comment: @JonSkeet added usings. I did have System.IO in both locations.

Comment: be explicit with `Stream` - qualify it with the namespace.

Comment: @DanielA.White replacing Stream with System.IO.Stream has the same result :(

Comment: is your interface project using a portable class library?

Comment: @DanielA.White I believe so. It was created as a xamarin forms project and says (Portable) in the Solution Explorer. I'm not sure if there's a better way to check.

Comment: I have done a similar thing with Stream and DI in a Forms PCL so I know it's possible.  Why is StreamProvider_iOS not public?  And in your Dependency attribute you should use the name of the class, not the interface.  Those are the two things that jump out as being different than my implementation.

Comment: @Jason I double checked both of those and they didn't help, thanks though. Do you recall if it was specifically PCL to iOS that you used Stream DI in?

Comment: Yes it was.  As a test, I would change Stream in both places to a string or void, just to see if it compiles, or if there are still errors.  That may help narrow down the underlying issue.

Comment: Is there any chance you accidentally created a Foo.Stream class? If you're using Visual Studio, it's very easy to unintentionally have VS create a class when you meant to bring in a namespace.